# Handle a POST request and write response to client socket

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to implement a proxy server.

I referred to the information in [this blog](http://blog.edendekker.me/a-java-proxy-server-with-caching-and-validation/).

1. The method handles GET request but doesn't handle some websites like www.facebook.com (a GET request). What could be the issue.
2. The method doesn't handle a POST request. How is handling a POST request and writing the response to client socket differ from handling a GET request.

Any pointers or reference links would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered reading the HTTP specs? They're pretty easily available.

Comment: "Doesn't handle some websites" is not an adequate problem description.