# HTTP socket programming java

Tags: java, http, sockets, tcp, network-programming

what would be the good starting point to learn TCP Socket programming using java.

I have reasonably good experience in java software programming but new to netwrk/socket programming.

I am working on to develop a proxy cache server. But not able to read post requests/302/405 requests.
I referred to this below code.

http://blog.edendekker.me/a-java-proxy-server-with-caching-and-validation/

But unable to modify the code to read urls like www.gmail.com that return 302 Moved Permanently Error OR 405 Method Not valid Error. And also not able to read POST requests.

What would be the starting point where I can read about handling errors and handling POST requests.
Any reference links,  example codes would be helpful.

My prev question in similar topic:

[Handle a POST request and write response to client socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112505/handle-a-post-request-and-write-response-to-client-socket#comment17826868_13112505)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problems are more related to **HTTP** than to TCP as such. Do you want to implement a proxy server in order to learn the HTTP protocol? If not, there are several good proxies freely available, often including source code. If you just want to learn TCP socket programming, try something simpler such as e.g. POP3. Also, if you want to do TCP in Java, be aware that there are 2 major ways to implement them:

- One thread per connection
- One thread per application, shared between connections ([Java NIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) and NIO2)

Assuming you really want to tackle the HTTP proxy. HTTP is not trivial if you want to implement all of the functionality that e.g. browsers use, like caching, authentication, etc. plus the additional complexities that incurs when implementing a proxy.

If you really want to bite the bullet, [here](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21.html)'s a more lightweight version of the HTTP protocol, for all the details, refer to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) . But be aware that RFC 2616, the HTTP 1.1 specification, refers to other RFCs that you might have to consult as well for specific areas such as authentication.

**Update**:
One other thing that might be easier in some cases is using an [HTTP proxy to sniff the communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944862/http-trace-utitlity/12967817#12967817) between say a browser and an off-the-shelf proxy to quickly see what others are doing.